# Integrate $\int \left [{2\over x(1+xy)}+{3y\over 1+xy}\right ]dx$

Tags: integration

I'm stuck with an integration $$\int\left [{2\over x(1+xy)}+{3y\over 1+xy}\right ]\text{d}x$$
Here y is constant.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $y$ is some constant ?

Comment: yeah, y is constant

Comment: what is the upper limit of integration?

Comment: it's an indefinite integral

Comment: partial fractions for the first, the second is logarithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{2}{x(1+xy)}= \dfrac{2}{x} - \dfrac{2y}{1+xy}, \displaystyle \int\dfrac{kydx}{1+xy}= k\ln(1+xy)+C, k = 2,3$ .

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \int \frac{2}{x(1+xy)}dx = 2\int \frac{1}{x}+2\int \frac{-y}{y(\frac{1}{y}+x)}$

$\displaystyle \int\frac{3y}{y(\frac{1}{y}+x)}dx$

Now evaluate both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint：
$$\begin{align*}
\int \left [ {2\over x(1+xy)}+{3y\over 1+xy} \right ]\mathrm{d}x&=2\int \left ( \frac{1}{x}-\frac{y}{1+xy} \right )\mathrm{d}x+3y\int \frac{1}{1+xy}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int \frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x+y\int \frac{1}{1+xy}\, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \int \frac{2 + 3xy}{x(1 + xy)}dx$

$\displaystyle \int \frac{2 + 2xy + xy}{x(1 + xy)}dx$

= $\displaystyle \int \frac{2 + 2xy}{x(1 + xy)} dx + \int \frac{xy}{x(1 + xy)} dx$

= $\displaystyle \int \left[\frac{2}{x} + \frac{y}{(1 + xy)}\right] dx$

= $\displaystyle \int \left[\frac{2}{x}  + \int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y} + x} \right]dx$

= $\displaystyle 2 \log|x| + \log|\frac1y + x| + c$